# Find duplicates by id in two indices in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have several indices for storing my data in week-related index, with template `myindex-2022-weekOfYear`

How to find all duplicates by id across these indices?

I've tried to used aggregations (based from another questions here)

```json
GET myindex-*/_search
{
  "stored_fields": [
    "myKey"
  ],
  "size": 100,
  "aggs": {
    "duplicateNames": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "myKey",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "duplicateDocuments": {
          "top_hits": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it looks like that query is not working properly, as searching a single document by id (from query result) returns only one index, so I assume that `min_doc_count` is not working as I am expecting.

EDIT:
I see in response:

```
"genres" : {
  "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 530,
  "sum_other_doc_count" : 357290963,
  "buckets" : [ ]
}
```

so probably shard_size is too low (and I cant really increase it, due to es resources)

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

I could not find why this is not working, but I made a POC which show it is working correctly.
(For a rather smalls dimensions)

## Poc

```json
POST _bulk
{"index": {"_index": "74473038-0", "_id": "1"}}
{"data": "some dummy data", "id": 1}
{"index": {"_index": "74473038-1", "_id": "1"}}
{"data": "some dummy data", "id": 1}
{"index": {"_index": "74473038-2", "_id": "1"}}
{"data": "some dummy data", "id": 1}
{"index": {"_index": "74473038-3", "_id": "1"}}
{"data": "some dummy data", "id": 1}
{"index": {"_index": "74473038-0", "_id": "2"}}
{"data": "some dummy data", "id": 2}
{"index": {"_index": "74473038-2", "_id": "2"}}
{"data": "some dummy data", "id": 2}
{"index": {"_index": "74473038-0", "_id": "3"}}
{"data": "some dummy data", "id": 3}
{"index": {"_index": "74473038-1", "_id": "3"}}
{"data": "some dummy data", "id": 3}
{"index": {"_index": "74473038-3", "_id": "3"}}
{"data": "some dummy data", "id": 3}
{"index": {"_index": "74473038-0", "_id": "4"}}
{"data": "some dummy data", "id": 4}
{"index": {"_index": "74473038-2", "_id": "4"}}
{"data": "some dummy data", "id": 4}
{"index": {"_index": "74473038-3", "_id": "4"}}
{"data": "some dummy data", "id": 4}
{"index": {"_index": "74473038-0", "_id": "5"}}
{"data": "some dummy data", "id": 5}

GET 74473038-*/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "duplicateNames": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "duplicateDocuments": {
          "top_hits": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting as expected, document with `id` : `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`.
Omitting `5`.

```json
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 4,
    "successful": 4,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 13,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "duplicateNames": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 1,
          "doc_count": 4,
          "duplicateDocuments": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 4,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "74473038-0",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "data": "some dummy data",
                    "id": 1
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index": "74473038-1",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "data": "some dummy data",
                    "id": 1
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index": "74473038-3",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "data": "some dummy data",
                    "id": 1
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 3,
          "doc_count": 3,
          "duplicateDocuments": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 3,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "74473038-0",
                  "_id": "3",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "data": "some dummy data",
                    "id": 3
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index": "74473038-1",
                  "_id": "3",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "data": "some dummy data",
                    "id": 3
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index": "74473038-3",
                  "_id": "3",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "data": "some dummy data",
                    "id": 3
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 4,
          "doc_count": 3,
          "duplicateDocuments": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 3,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "74473038-3",
                  "_id": "4",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "data": "some dummy data",
                    "id": 4
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index": "74473038-2",
                  "_id": "4",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "data": "some dummy data",
                    "id": 4
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index": "74473038-0",
                  "_id": "4",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "data": "some dummy data",
                    "id": 4
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 2,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "duplicateDocuments": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 2,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "74473038-2",
                  "_id": "2",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "data": "some dummy data",
                    "id": 2
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index": "74473038-0",
                  "_id": "2",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "data": "some dummy data",
                    "id": 2
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I see in response:

    "genres" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 530,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 357290963,
      "buckets" : [ ]
    }


so probably shard_size is too low (and I cant really increase it, due to es resources)